# How to extract all matches as array by parsing a JSON message using AWS CloudWatch Logs Insights?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I log messages that are JSON objects. The JSON has an array that contains objects with id:

```
{
   ...
   "arr": [{"typeId": 1, "foo": "bar"}, {"typeId": 10, "foo": "other"}, ...],
   ...
}
```

Now I want to count usage of objects by type by counting all occurrences of their corresponding ID in the array.

I've tried the following query:

```
filter @message like '"typeId":'
| parse @message '"typeId":*,' as id
| stats count(id) as objCount by id
| sort objCount desc
```

Which produces a result:

| id | objCount |
| --- | --- |
| 113 | 28 |
| 1 | 12 |
| 296 | 10 |
| 2 | 9 |

But it looks wrong. It seems to extract only the very first ID value from each message. I know it because if I search logs by `filter @message like '"typeId":113,'` I get 44 occurrences.

How can I extract all matches by using `parse`?